# Is there a signed version of ValueInjecter that I can GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, gac, valueinjecter

Is there a signed version of ValueInjecter that I can GAC? I need a version that is strong named so that it can be GAC'ed.

Comment: What language is this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the one from nuget, and the one that you download from codeplex are both signed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.